# Cloud explorer web client

Tags: javascript, web, client, cloud, explorer

Does anyone knows a javascript based open sources cloud explorer. I look for something more for the UI. I want to use it as a base to integrate capabilities for managing multiple accounts and communicate between them. Adding audio,photo, video player etc.

Thank' s in advance!

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean by 'cloud explorer'?

Comment: Someehing that i can use to connect to a cloud and managing it. Sync/download/upload etc.

Comment: Mostly what i need is user interface with a tree view and some basic interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many 'file explorer'-type tree views. For example (from a superficial Google Search): https://www.jstree.com/ or https://www.uptickhq.com/react-keyed-file-browser/ for React.js. You would have to handle the 'multiple accounts that communicate with each other' separately to implementing the tree view.

This would likely be in form of a server-based API that did this and passed data to your client, where your tree used the information from the API to draw the tree, or you could probably use a library like `browser-request`/`jquery-ajax`/etc. to fetch from your different accounts directly to your browser (bearing in mind that there are probably some CORS limitations for this).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very helpful.